# iOS Local Area Network Authorization Status

Tags: ios, swift, ios-privacy-settings

I have developed an app for which permission for `Local Area Network` permission is mandatory to give. As this permission will be asked as soon as the app opens, sometimes users will miss this dialog and deny the permission by mistake.

From Apple forum thread, it's pretty much clear that I can not ask for the permission for second time similar to the other permissions in iOS. But I want to know if the permission is disabled in user's iPhone so that I can show some appropriate alert saying that this permission is needed.

Like we do in `CoreLocation`

```
myManager. authorizationStatus
```

I was just wondering if same thing can be done for `Local Area Network` permission?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the solutions given in the following URL :

[iOS 14 How to trigger Local Network dialog and check user answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940427/ios-14-how-to-trigger-local-network-dialog-and-check-user-answer)

I hope it works.

Comment: If you believe that a question is a duplicate then you should flag it as such.