# Cannot run flutter http server successfully on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, httpserver

According to [flutter-dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpServer-class.html) I try to run dart code ( same as [shelf-example bin/server.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/blob/master/server/simple/bin/server.dart) ) .

**It works on my Android device**, because when I run `curl -v "http://{my Android device LAN ip}:8080/helloworld"`, my Android device return `Hello, World!` quickly.

**But when it runs on my iPhone12 (iOS 16.0.2), when I run `curl -v "http://{my iOS device LAN ip}:8080/helloworld"`, curl will raise error below**

```bash
*   Trying {my iOS device LAN ip}:8080...
* connect to {my iOS device LAN ip} port 8080 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to {my iOS device LAN ip} port 8080 after 75004 ms: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to {my iOS device LAN ip} port 8080 after 75004 ms: Operation timed out
```

ping {my iOS device LAN ip} is ok

```bash
PING {my iOS device LAN ip} ({my iOS device LAN ip}): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from {my iOS device LAN ip}: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=249.370 ms
64 bytes from {my iOS device LAN ip}: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=171.025 ms
64 bytes from {my iOS device LAN ip}: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=92.354 ms
```

telnet other port (such as 8081) will suddenly raise error `Connection refused`, when 8080 will wait a while and raise error `Operation timed out`.

So I think the dart code part is ok, but some important network config need to set.

So I have tried to add text bellow in `Info-Debug.plist` and `Info-Release.plist` but it not works.

```
    <key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Desp</string>
    <key>NSBonjourServices</key>
    <array>
        <string>_dartobservatory._tcp</string>
    </array>
```

Is there any aspect I haven't considered? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I think the dart code part is ok, but some important network config need to set.

After some days search, finally I get the key bug: ***Local Network Usage Permission***.

Following to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67758105/7090598) , I add those code to `Info.plist` and `xxx.swift`, and agree the permission request dialog, finally, the http request can send to iPhone-Http-Server.