# In iOS 16 is a way to check if user has granted local network access permission?

Tags: swift, ios16

In iOS 16 is a way to check if user has granted local network access permission?

In iOS 15 and before, there is no accurate way to do it. How is iOS 16 now? Any new ways or more accurate way to do it?

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681971

Comment: Does this answer your question: [iOS 14 How to trigger Local Network dialog and check user answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940427/ios-14-how-to-trigger-local-network-dialog-and-check-user-answer)?

Comment: It's not applicable since the question is about iOS 16, the behavior kept changing in this area during different versions.