# How to trigger the local network dialog authorization for multicast entitlement using iOS 14

Tags: ios, networking, multicast, ios14, entitlements

Following iOS 14 new policy of blocking access to local network, a com.apple.developer.networking.multicast special entitlement is needed to access the local network, and this access should be confirmed by user during an authorization dialog. Although this new feature is not thoroughly documented, Apple engineers have indicated in forums that this authorization dialog popup is only triggered when the app tries to send traffic, causing an issue for apps reading only the network, as indicated in [iOS 14 How to trigger Local Network dialog and check user answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940427/ios-14-how-to-trigger-local-network-dialog-and-check-user-answer)

Unfortunately, the advice of sending some data to trigger the authorization dialog does not seem to work in our case, as we never got the popup dialog appearing.

Our app usually only receive UDP broadcast (no transmit except in a few cases). We have got the com.apple.developer.networking.multicast entitlement, have added it to our app entitlements, have added the requested NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription in our Info.plist and are signing our app manually using XCode 12.0 with a provisioning profile including this entitlement (manual code signing is needed in this case as indicated in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656773?answerId=628537022). Since then, situation has somewhat improved as the UDP packet reception that was fully blocked before adding the entitlement started to work sometimes, but unfortunately not always (situation seems worse on iOS 14.0.1 than on iOS 14 and on iPhone than on iPad).

Most importantly, we never got the authorization dialog displayed and our app does not appear as authorized in Privacy/Local Network (even when UDP reception works). We suspect this may be the cause for this spurious reception issue. As it seems the authorization dialog is only shown when sending data, we configured our app to send data to the local network to try to trigger the dialog, using all below methods:

- TcpSocket class (using CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost) to connect to 192.168.1.1 on port 80 and send a few bytes (there is a device at this address)
- using GCDAsyncSocket to connect and send a test TCP packet to same address/port
- using GCDAsyncUdpSocket to create a UDP socket, enabling it for broadcast, then joinMulticastGroup 224.0.1.0 and broadcasting a test UDP packet on port 80.
- using GCDAsyncUdpSocket to create a UDP socket, enabling it for broadcast, then broadcasting a test UDP packet on port 80 to 255.255.255.255.
- reusing the example from Apple article (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=0oi77447) sending multicast packets with NWConnectionGroup to 224.0.1.0
- and finally using the triggerDialog() method of class LocalNetworkPermissionService indicated in [iOS 14 How to trigger Local Network dialog and check user answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63940427/6057764)

None of the above actions triggered the authorization dialog on iOS 14.0 and iOS 14.0.1, and our app is still not listed as authorized in Privacy/Local Network, with spurious reception of UDP packets.

If somebody has encountered the same issue and found a solution, many thanks for your advice.

Comment: Have you seen https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663858? FAQ-2 indicates that you don't need the permission for multicast receives but you will do shortly. FAQ-8 suggests a way to trigger the alert (probably the one you tried). Also, when the dialog fails to appear, have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling?

Comment: @Columbo thanks for your reply. Yes, we are closely following this thread and implemented their recommended solution to trigger the alert, to no avail. But following your advice of uninstalling/reinstalling, we finally have done that and this worked! Many thanks for your help. However, this solution will be complicated to implement for our users because our app stores a lot of data, and reinstalling from scratch and restoring data will be a time consuming operation. It is not normal an existing app should be wholly deinstalled/installed again for the network dialog authorization to appear.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Columbo and help from Apple, a solution has been found, although the root cause of the issue is not yet fully understood.

Our app was built with a iOS release deployment target of 9.0 because we tried to preserve compatibility with older devices. It seems a deployment target lower 12.0 may cause issue with the network privacy management. The solution was then:

- to rebuild the app after updating the iOS deployment target to 12.0 or higher.
- for all iOS 14.0 and 14.0.1 devices having a previous version of the app already installed, to fully delete the app and install it again (updating the app was not sufficient, the network privacy alert was still not shown).

Of course, this procedure is not ideal for users that will have to reinstall the app from scratch and configure it again. I will update this thread if a future version of iOS avoids this issue.

**Update:** when using iOS 14.2, the app is correctly triggering the network privacy alert even after an upgrade (without full deletion and reinstall). We then recommended our users to upgrade to 14.2 before upgrading our app. We have kept the deployment target at 12.0

Comment: Hi all, we are having similar issues and discussing on the Apple forums thread here
https://developers.apple.com/forums/thread/666179?page=1#645696022

Comment: @Nick T, thanks for the pointer. We got great help from Eskimo and our app is now triggering correctly the network privacy authorization dialog after an update, but only under iOS 14.2

Answer (score 2):

To those who suddenly find that APP ask this authorization, and don't suppose it appear. The answer is that maybe your APP trying to connect to your test server which in same LAN with your iPhone running iOS 14.

Answer (score 1):

For 14.2, the local network access is handled little better and there is a sample code used to trigger this alert as mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663768

Also you can create dummy connection using NWConnection, this will trigger system dialogue for asking permission (if system dialogue is not shown anytime before) and check the local network access is allowed or not as mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663769 , this is available from iOS 14.2.